# PHP and jQuery - Save created jQuery forms

Tags: php, jquery, html, hyperlink

So here is my dilemma I am trying to save these forms to pages that are created. I have a jQuery system that can add inputs to the list like so:

But I have to save them to the page, so create them dynamically through jQuery and save it using PHP. I have the right idea I just don't know where to start with it. Any help is appreciated here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    var labelDiv = $('.addEmail');
    var i = $('.customSpan2').size() + 1;

    $('#addEmail').live('click', function() {
            $('<div class="span5 customSpan2"><label class="customLabel removable">Email '+ i +':</label><form class="bs-docs-example notif-form"><div class="row emailRow"><input type="text" class="inputEmail" placeholder="hotelmobi@mobi.com" name="emailform_'+ i +'" /> <a id="delInput">Remove</a></div></form></div>').appendTo(labelDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#delInput').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 1 ) {
                    $(this).parent('div').remove();
                    $('div.customSpan2').remove();
                    i = 1;
                    // i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
```

});

HTML

```
                                <div class="span5 pushDown tempPush">
                                <label class="customLabel"><?php echo $lang[$cur_lang]['email']; ?>:</label>
                                <form class="bs-docs-example notif-form">
                                    <div class="row emailRow">
                                        <input type="text" class="inputEmail" placeholder="hotelmobi@mobi.com">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="addEmail"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pushDown">
                        <div class="span3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="span6 offset2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-medium" id="addEmail" style="margin-left: -13px;"><?php echo $lang[$cur_lang]['addEmail']; ?></button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium btn-fix"><?php echo $lang[$cur_lang]['save']; ?></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: So you are trying to create the forms using jQuery and save the page using PHP? Or are your users creating the forms?

Comment: The users create the forms. I'm trying to max it out at 3 and disable the button then too. I'm having some weird things happen with that too haha.

Comment: Like I have everything set up on a couchbase database and I am trying to link it up to that.

Comment: So your database would have columns for page and inputs, and you need to insert the user's form details (# and types of inputs) to the database after form creation?

Answer (score 0):

Inspite of trying to save these form in page try to save these newly added input detail into database and every time manipulate these from database and show on required page.

For this you just have to save input type, input_type_id, and value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, .live function is deprecated form jQuery 1.7
I would crate an event for a button like this:

```
$('#addEmail').click(function() {
        $('<div class="span5 customSpan2"><label class="customLabel removable">Email '+ i +':  </label><form class="bs-docs-example notif-form"><div class="row emailRow"><input type="text" class="inputEmail" placeholder="hotelmobi@mobi.com" name="emailform_'+ i +'" /> <a id="delInput">Remove</a></div></form></div>').appendTo(labelDiv);
        i++;
});
```

If you want to send/receive data without refreshing the page, refer AJAX technology. jQuery can reduce obtrusive codes when you're doing it.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/